# How to diagnose "Perhaps you need to add xxx to the build-depends in your .cabal file", when it is already in the cabal file?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I think the only interesting bits are my imports and my cabal file. Here are the imports and the demonstration of how I would use the problematic import (`Database.CQL.IO.Log`).

```
module FDS.Database.Cassandra where

import           Prelude                         hiding(init)
import           Database.CQL.IO                 as Client hiding(Logger)
import           Database.CQL.IO.Log             as CQLLog
import qualified Database.CQL.Protocol           as CQL
import           Numeric.Natural
import           System.Logger                   (Logger)

cqlLogger :: Logger -> CQLLog.Logger
cqlLogger logger = undefined
```

However, I get the error:

```
src/FDS/Database/Cassandra.hs:7:1: error:                                                                                              
    Could not load module `Database.CQL.IO.Log'                                                                                                                                    
    It is a member of the hidden package `cql-io-1.1.0'.                                                                                                                           
    Perhaps you need to add `cql-io' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.                                                                                                     
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.                                                                                                                                
  |                                                                                                                                                                                
7 | import           Database.CQL.IO.Log             as CQLLog                                                                                                                     
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But as we can see from the cabal file, it is there:

```
library
  ghc-options:    -Wall -Wtabs -Wincomplete-record-updates
  default-extensions:
      OverloadedStrings

  exposed-modules:
    FDS
    , FDS.Config.Core
    , FDS.Config.Dhall
    , FDS.Data.Util
    , FDS.Database.Cassandra

  other-modules:
    FDS.Data.Hobo.Defs

  build-depends:
    prelude
    , base-noprelude    ^>=4.12
    , bytestring        ^>=0.10.8.2
    , conduit           ^>=1.3.1
    , containers        ^>=0.6
    , cql               ^>=4.0.1
    , cql-io            ^>=1.1.0
```

One thing to note, I do have cql-io in my `extra-deps` in `stack.yaml`, as the latest version wasn't yet in LTS.

**Q&A from Comments**

**Q** Are there other components in your cabal file (e.g. executables, benchmarks, test suites)?

**A** Yes

**Q** Do they also use FDS.Database.Cassandra (but perhaps without depending on cql-io)?

**A** Not yet, but plan to later. So I haven't touched the other components yet.

**Q** Does the version of cql-io chosen by your build tool still export Database.CQL.IO.Log?

**A** It [seems to do so](https://gitlab.com/twittner/cql-io/blob/v1.1.0/cql-io.cabal#L83).

**Q** What is the exact command you are running when you see that error?

**A** `stack --nix build` The only interesting bit that `--nix` is doing (AFAIK) is pulling in required system packages, e.g., OpenSSL.

Comment: Are there other components in your cabal file (e.g. executables, benchmarks, test suites)? Do they also use FDS.Database.Cassandra (but perhaps without depending on cql-io)? Does the version of cql-io chosen by your build tool still export Database.CQL.IO.Log? What is the exact command you are running when you see that error?

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks for the insightful questions - I answered them in the original question

Comment: Note that the `Database.CQL.IO.Log` module is actually in the `cql-io-lib` sublibrary, not `cql-io` itself. It's basically a hidden module. I think the error message is not up-to-date with how the new sublibraries feature works. Cf. https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4206 – `cql-io-lib` would need to be declared as `visibility: public` in the `cql-io.cabal` file to allow you to use it externally.

Comment: ah, i see, i missed that in the cql-io.cabal file! Still investigating, but if I add cql-io-lib I'm told I need to add it to `extra-deps` in `stack.yaml`, and if I add it there, I get "The following package identifiers were not found in your indices: cql-io-lib-1.1.0 ". So guessing stack can't handle this yet.

Comment: Hmm, in the last comment (currnetly) in that issue tracker, it is stated "`visibility: public` in the sublibrary stanza." is required for external use of the sub library ... don't see it, so maybe I should take that up with the library developer(s).

Comment: @bbarker As hinted in @leftaroundabout's previous comment, this is not stack's fault: the cql-io cabal file does not make that module (nor the `cql-io-lib` library) available externally, perhaps on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The comments above were very insightful for the general case of the question (as posed); the answer being, sub-libraries that are recently supported by cabal may not have `visibility: true` declared.

But in my specific case, the answer is to look at the problematic library's re-exports. I could get around this issue because the cql-io authors re-exported `Logger (..)` and `LogLevel(..)` from the main library.

So that would allow me to write my code.

An even better answer that is very specific to my situation, as I was trying to use TinyLog, is that there [is a library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cql-io-tinylog) for that already ... [here is the code](https://gitlab.com/romanb/cql-io-tinylog/blob/master/src/Database/CQL/IO/Tinylog.hs) from that library that demonstrates how to get around the issue (and solves the problem for me completely, as I now shouldn't have to write any code).

Here is the relevant excerpt:

```
module Database.CQL.IO.Tinylog (mkLogger) where

import Data.ByteString.Builder
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)
import Database.CQL.IO (Logger (..), LogLevel (..))
import Database.CQL.IO.Hexdump

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified System.Logger        as Tiny

-- | Create a cql-io 'Logger' that delegates log messages to
-- the given tinylog 'Tiny.Logger'. Requests and responses are
-- logged on 'Tiny.Trace' level.
mkLogger :: Tiny.Logger -> Logger
mkLogger l = Logger
    { logMessage  = tinylogMessage  l
    , logRequest  = tinylogRequest  l
    , logResponse = tinylogResponse l
    }
```

And here is how I adjusted my imports in the example above to confirm and get GHC happy (though I will scrap this now in favor of using `cql-io-tinylog`):

```
import           Prelude                         hiding(init, log)
import           Database.CQL.IO                 hiding(Logger)
import qualified Database.CQL.IO                 as CQLIO
import qualified Database.CQL.Protocol           as CQL
import           Numeric.Natural
import           System.Logger                   hiding(defSettings)
```